# How do I set the background of UITableViewCell appropriately?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've set the colour of my UITableViewCell as follows:

```
UIColor *RedCell = [UIColor colorWithRed:(199/255.0)  green:(0/255.0)  blue:(39/255.0)  alpha:0.2];
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = RedCell;
```

However, you can see in the screenshot that it is creeping outside the border of the cell.  What's the appropriate way to set the background so this doesn't happen?

[image: UITableViewCell]

Comment: Try setting the background color on the cell's background view instead of its content view

Comment: Yup, that did it!  Stick this in an answer and earn yourself some points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For grouped tableview cells, you should set the background color on the background view, instead of the content view (which I assume is a clear background).

Comment: this works well, although apple suggests otherwise. See my answer. The reason behind this is that they may change th internal structure of cells in the future, but cell.backgroundcolor will always be supported.

Answer (score 0):

try cell.backgroundColor, as per the docs

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1

You shouldnt modify the contentView, exceptz to add subviews to it.
For a full understanding of how TableViews work, read the provided link.
Trust me, it is worth your time.